# Number of distinct elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

This is a objective question asked in an exam

Let $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...x_{n}$   $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}$ be distinct Reals. Define the set A={$(f_{1}(t),f_{2}(t),f_{3}(t),f_{4}(t),....f_{n}(t)):$  t $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}$} where for 1$\leq$k$<$n
where $f_{k}(t)$=1 if $x_{k}\leq t$ and   $f_{k}(t)$=0 if $x_{k}> t$

We are asked to find the number of distinct elements in set A

My Approach so far has been that as all $x_{i}$ is distinct, there are $n+1$ possible places which t can occupy e.g., t is smaller than exactly 2 xis and so on... hence the total possible distinct elements is $n+1$

Comment: Yes: each element of $A$ consists of $k$ ones followed by $n-k$ zeroes, where $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: You can reorder $x_1,...,x_n$ in ascending order and then do the same with $f_1(t),f_2(t),...$(meaning to put the indexes in the same order) without loss of generality.